# Bootstrap and javascript / Jquery in android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a website that works in Google Chrome and other major browsers. I want to publish it for Android. So I used PhoneGap to convert to Android. One problem was that PhoneGap does not use Bootstrap anymore, nor my JQuery.
Can you maybe help me because I can't find any clear explanation for how to fix this. Do I need to add something to the project in PhoneGap or is it easier in Android Studio instead of PhoneGap? 
I thank you in advanced for helping me. I am really new to Android.

The Header

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Clash Royal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/screen.css">
</head>
```

The script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: How did you link to your bootstrap and Jquery?

Comment: I haved the header linking and the script linking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Clash Royal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/screen.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Script

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

I need to download it local and also link it local and then it works